# Can I inject posted image files into PDF using dompdf?

Tags: php, pdf, laravel, laravel-4, dompdf

I have a form where users can fill input boxes. In some cases, they're allowed to select images too.

The problem is, I don't want to save the image file somewhere on our server and give PDF the URL like this:

```
//Put uploaded file on public/uploads/ folder
<img src="{{ $imagePath }}" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
```

Instead, I'd like to inject uploaded image directly into PDF file. Something like this:

```
PDF::load($data, 'A4', 'portrait')->inject('image', Input::file('resim'))->output();
//So I can reference it as {{ $image }} on PDF template, but image will be injected into PDF file
```

I'm beginner on PDF files and I'm not even sure if this is possible.

If it's possible, can anyone give me some advices?

Ps. I use DOMPDF package for Laravel 4. https://github.com/thujohn/pdf-l4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to be able to reference the image somehow in your document. There are a few ways you could do this.

*Access the temporary file from the uploads.*

In your HTML file just reference the temporary file created by the upload as your image source, e.g.

```
<img src="<?php echo $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']; ?>">
```

*Capture the content of the image and write it into the HTML as a data-uri value*

dompdf understands [data-uris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and so you could take the uploaded file, convert it to a data-uri, and insert that into your HTML.

You do have to detect the image format, which can require a bit more work depending on your version of PHP. With v5.3+ you can use the [finfo_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) method. If that extension isn't available you can perform some basic content-type detection by parsing the file extension.

In my example I'm just specifying PNG as the image type.

```
<?php
// detect mime type, but I'm forcing PNG
$mime = 'image/png';
?>
<img src="<?php echo 'data:' , $mime , ';base64,' , base64_encode( file_get_contents( $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] ) ); ?>">
```

Comment: I was using the first option. I'm sure data uris will come handy sometime!

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my HTML...

```
<body>
 <img src="{{ URL::asset('img/my-image.png') }}" />
            my route where i have my img
```

and this in my controller

```
public function getPdf($id){

   $html = View::make("backend.PDF.batch")->with('batchs',$batchs)->with('ad',$ad)->render();

         return PDF::load($html, 'A4', 'portrait')->show();
}
```

and in the view don't show me the img they say

```
DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE is set to FALSE
```